# Discord Rich presence

Tags: python, discord

So basically I'm trying to have my account on discord online 24/7 so I wrote a bit code for that in python, now I want to add a rich presence, with a timer (how much time elapsed since I started the game) a game title, a large image key and all of that stuff and I have no idea how to write it, anyone knows how to help?

My code so far in main.py...

````
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

client = commands.Bot(
command_prefix=':',
self_bot=True
)


game = discord.Game("Game Title")


@client.event
async def on_connect():
 await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)
 
 


keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"), bot=False)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Using self bots is actually against the terms of service. Instead of using `discord.py` use `pypresense` You can do a lot more with it.

This is an example of time elapsed

```
from pypresence import Presence
import time

"""
You need to upload your image(s) here:
https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/<APP ID>/rich-presence/assets
"""

client_id = "client_id"  # Enter your Application ID here.
RPC = Presence(client_id=client_id)
RPC.connect()


# Make sure you are using the same name that you used when uploading the image
start_time=time.time() # Using the time that we imported at the start. start_time equals time.
RPC.update(large_image="LARGE_IMAGE_HERE", large_text="Programming B)",
            small_image="SMALL_IMAGE_HERE", small_text="Hello!", start=start_time) # We want to apply start time when you run the presence.

while 1:
    time.sleep(15) #Can only update presence every 15 seconds
```

You can install it using `pip install pypresence`

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, and I am sorry if this is not what you are looking for, but discord.py is not made for user-bots (atleast not intended), I recommend using something like lewdneko's pypresence. It has bizzare compatibility/detection (Linux, especially Arch) issues but when it works, it works very well actually. It also has an attribute for `time_elapsed`, which you can use with something like `time.time()`. (afaik)

Comment: This package was already recommended in the previous answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. PC was lagging out terribly back then, xd.